# Creating words with every letter combination possible

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to make program in javascript that makes words of given letters (e.g. given letters: "a,b,c", words: "aaaa", "aaab"... and so on.

```
const random = (length = 6) => {
    // Declare all characters
    let chars = 'aąbcćdeęfghijklłmnńoópqrsśtuvwxyzźżAĄBCĆDEĘFGHIJKLŁMNŃOÓPQRSŚTUVWXYZŹŻ';

    // Pick characters randomly
    let str = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        str += chars.charAt(i);
    }

    return str;
};
```

Is there any way to do it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: This code will only return the first 6 characters, you should try some more things and come back with more specific questions

Comment: I know, but I'm trying to make 4 or 6 letter word with "aaaa".... combinations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you're looking for is every *possible* combination of letters, randomness isn't the way to do this.

Try taking a more methodical approach

```
combinations = []

function allPossibleCombinations(lettersRemaining, lettersSoFar){
   if (lettersRemaining.length == 0){
      combinations.push(lettersSoFar);
   }else{
      for (var i = 0; i < lettersRemaining.length; i++){
         allPossibleCombinations(lettersSoFar + lettersRemaining.charAt(i), lettersRemaining.slice(0, i) + lettersRemaining.slice(i + 1))
      }
   }
}
```

The code is untested, but this general recursive approach should work

Comment: I know randomness isnt the right thing, I just didnt remove comments and function name :), thx for reply, gonna try this rn